# How to add UITapGestureRecognizer on GMSMapView ios

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, gmsmapview

I've given blinking effect on GMSMapView where the pin drop. So as per requirement i've used 5 images for blinking effect.Now i want that if i click on image than screen should be navigate.  So i've added UITapGestureRecognizer. But its not working.

Below is the code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
[self.img_splashRound4 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[self.img_splashRound4 setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self.img_splashRound4 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

    [self acceptRequest];

}
```

Can any one guide me??

Comment: Try enabling user interaction for parent view of self.img_splashRound4

Comment: @Arun i've already done     [self.map_googleMap setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];